# change variables from an other view controller when a textField is changed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change the values of a variable in two different view controllers from the value of a textField but I don't understand how to use the delegate so that it works.

My Storyboard:

[image]

My Code:

MainView:

```
class GameCreatingViewController: UIViewController {
    var newGame = Game()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        newGame = Game()
        newGame.playerBook.NumberOfPlayers = 2
        if let vc = self.children.first(where: { $0 is PlayersTableViewController }) as? PlayersTableViewController {
            vc.currentGame = self.newGame
            vc.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        if let vc = self.children.first(where: { $0 is GameViewController }) as? GameViewController {
            vc.currentGame = self.newGame
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func changeName(name: String, number: Int) {
        self.newGame.playerBook.players[number].name = name
    }
}
```

tableViewController:

```
class PlayersTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
   
    var currentGame = Game()
   
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "playerCell", for: indexPath) as? PlayerNameTableViewCell else {fatalError("Wrong type of cell")}

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.playerName.delegate = self
        
        let row = indexPath[1]+1
        cell.numberOfPlayer = row
        return cell
    }
    func changeName(name: String, number: Int) {
        self.currentGame.playerBook.players[number].name = name
    }
    
}
```

The Cell:

```
protocol changeNameDelegate: class {
    func changeName(name: String, number: Int)
}
class PlayerNameTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    weak var delegate: changeNameDelegate? = nil
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var playerName: UITextField!
    
    var numberOfPlayer: Int = Int()
   
    
    @IBAction func changeName(_ sender: UITextField) {
        delegate?.changeName(name: sender.text!, number: numberOfPlayer)
        
    }

}
```

It seems like the action from the button executes but the fonctions from the other viewcontrollers don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the delegate to notify the other viewController.

Make sure isn't nil.

Usually protocols name the first letter is capitalized.
A good practice is to implement protocols in extensions.

Implement the `changeNameDelegate` protocol.

```
class PlayersTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, changeNameDelegate {
```

And in the cell configuration set the delegate.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "playerCell", for: indexPath) as? PlayerNameTableViewCell else {fatalError("Wrong type of cell")}

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.playerName.delegate = self

        cell.delegate = self // This line is missing.

        let row = indexPath[1]+1
        cell.numberOfPlayer = row
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I tried it (I updated the question) but it don't seem to execute the function.

Comment: Someone has to be implementing the delegate. 

Make sure you assign some class to implement it.

Ex: 

On cellForRowAt 

cell.delegate = self